# Proof of Cesàro summation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, summation, epsilon-delta

This is a proof I came up with while working on the textbook *Understanding Analysis*:

Supposing $x_{n} \rightarrow x$, we have that

$$s_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k \rightarrow x$$

Let $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

Notice that by the triangle equality we get: $$\vert  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k - x \vert = \vert \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}  (x_k - x) \vert \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \vert x_k - x \vert$$

Now, since $x_{n} \rightarrow x$, we know that for each $n>N$ term, we can make $\vert x_n - x \vert$ as small as we wish. Let $M = \max(x_{1},...,x_{N})$, and let $ \vert x_n - x \vert < \vert \frac{\epsilon n - MN}{n-N}\vert$. Then assuming $\epsilon n - MN > 0$ we get that

$$\vert  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k - x \vert \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \vert x_k - x \vert < \frac{NM + (n-N)\vert \frac{\epsilon n - MN}{n-N}\vert}{n} = \frac{MN + \epsilon n - MN}{n} = \epsilon$$

Notice, finally, that the assumption that $\epsilon n - MN > 0$ is harmless. This is since we let $n>\frac{MN}{\epsilon}$, after which the rest of the proof falls into place.

Comment: What's the question? Also, do you mean $x_n \rightarrow x$ or do you mean $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \rightarrow x$?

Comment: There is an issue where you write "for each $n>N$ term we can make $|x_n-x|$ as small as we like". This not exactly true -- if we have $\epsilon_0>0$, then we can find an $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon_0$ for all $n>N$, but this does not ensure $|x_n-x|$ is "arbitrarily small" for all $n>N$. You fix $N$ and then try to use it in bounds you want to impose on the $|x_k-x|$, whereas for *all* $k \geq N$ the most we know is that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon_0$. On the other hand, certainly there is an increasing sequence $(N_k)_{k \geq 0}$ with $|x_n-x|<\epsilon_0/2^k$ for all $n \geq N_k$.